# ffmpeg creates a broken video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, bugs

The video created by this command:

```bsh
ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -i picture.png -i sound.wav -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -preset medium -acodec aac -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

is not accepted ("Video assets: Your mezzanine file has failed.") by Amazon Prime.

How to make a video accepted by such a third party?

Comment: Ask the third party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video input is a single frame, which lasts 0.04 seconds. Likely the cause of your submission failure. Loop the image indefinitely and then tell ffmpeg to stop output file with shortest stream (the audio).

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 25 -loop 1 -i picture.png -i sound.wav -vf scale=1280:-2,format=yuv420p -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 -preset medium -acodec aac -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 200M output.mp4`